# How i customized success.phtml page in magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to change success message after submitting my checkout form. 
/var/www/HTML/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml
This success file I want to customized. On my side, I have so many catalog id for the product. But I want only particular catalog id (made in India(406)). Only this catalog id I want different success message. Like this think I want:-

Time check 16:01 PM to next day 15:59 PM. The parcel will be delivered next day. The user can check this by entering the pin code in the text box. For e.g., I ordered one product at 23:31 PM on 17th August 2016, then the user should be notified "Purchase now to get the parcel tomorrow. To check your eligibility please enter your pin code in the text box".

Please Help Me.....

Comment: Create an observer for order save after event store catalog ids in session and on success page fetch catalog ids from session if the catalog id which you want is exist in session show your custom message otherwise default message.

Comment: Thank you your response Sarfaraz bheda. If possible you provide me code how to do this think. What you tell me.

Comment: Sorry but SO is not a free coding service. Good luck!